# Mystery: 4 Bytes should represent a Date, but how?

Tags: c#, smartcard, winscard

So I've been able to read some unsecured values from an official German smartcard.
It works fine for Numbers and Strings, but I can't wrap my head around how to interpret Dates.

The date I want to read is specified as 4 Byte Date as seen in the spec: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4Zzs.jpg

The four bytes I read are:

```
0x4f 0x41 0x8d 0x00 (hex)
0100 1111 0100 0001 1000 1101 0000 0000 (binary)
```

and should represent this date: 20.02.2012
binary:

```
20 - 0001 0100
02 - 0000 0010
2012 - 0111 1101 1100
```

Another one:

```
0x58 0xAA 0x31 0x7f (hex)
0101 1000 1010 1010 0011 0001 0111 1111 (binary)
```

should represent: 19.02.2017

```
19 - 0001 0011
02 - 0010
2017 - 0111 1110 0001
```

Please help me to solve this Encoding-Riddle

---

The data from the card can be read by a commercial software, so I guess the raw data I get is usable in any way.

For the interested:
The vendor has a very huge specification which I've searched for numerous times (http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=CELEX:32002R1360:DE:NOT Available in multiple Languages)
The structure of the card is first mentioned on page 119

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The linked specification says that `cardIssueDate`  is of type `TimeReal` (Section 2.20.). The same specification defines `TimeReal` as the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT (i.e. [UNIX time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)) encoded as [ASN.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASN.1) INTEGER (Section 2.110.).

Comment: :( you are right. I even thought about that but made a mistake while verifying it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Which is using Big Endian / MSB to the left, don't forget to check you are using Big Endian regardless of the platform.